# How do i import only bootstrap forms styles to my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails app with a stylesheet called styles.css.scss and when i write `@import "bootstrap"` it applies bootstrap to the whole application like the texts and stuff, how do i say i want to only use the bootstrap theme for forms only and not have it mess with my apps texts? I did some googling but with no luck in finding something that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the form styles, then just import the form.less file alone into your project:

```
@import "forms"
```

Don't forget to add the proper classes in your HTML markup.

EDIT:

If you are using sass, it's the same idea:

in the bootstrap/bootstrap.scss file, comment all the lines but `@import "forms";`

Comment: am using the bootstrap-sass?